# Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "Microsoft.Office.Core".

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am using Visual Studio 2010 version, OS is Windows 10 and excel version is 2016. There is a project code in my Visual studio which was being written when my system's OS was 32 bit. But when few days back my system's OS got upgraded to 64 bit then whenever am trying to execute my project, am getting this warning (and no error)"Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "Microsoft.Office.Core". Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit."
I can outrun this and the tool is working fine but the problem am facing is that now I am not able to debug my code. Even if I using a debugger, still am not able to debug the code from the point of debugger, rather the code executes entirely at one go.
Kindly help.

Comment: what's the target configuration for your project?